# Angular 7 - Production mode: I can't navigate through page using the tab key

Tags: javascript, angular, server, navigation, accessibility

I'm experiencing a problem that i really haven't been able to figure out! When i run my angular 7 project on dev mode (ng serve) i'm able to navigate through my page (forms, links, buttons, etc) using the tab key. When i run ng serve --prod and run the project locally (localhost) the tab navigation also works. But strangely when i put the production build in my server the tab key stops working.

I'm leaving here my angular.json file, since my best shot is that this problem is related to some config (just don't know which one)

I've googled and googled again but wasn't able to find anything related...

```
 {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Marketplace": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets/ubrest",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              "src/assets/ubrest/favicon.ico",
              "src/.htaccess"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote-lite.css",
              "node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css",
              "node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css",  
              "node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.css",
              "src/assets/ubrest/sass/styles.scss"        
              ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/assets/ubrest/sass"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote-lite.js",
              "node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js",
              "node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.min.js",
              "node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Marketplace:build",
            "port": 8080
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Marketplace:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Marketplace:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css",
              "src/assets/sass/styles.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Marketplace-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Rhizom Marketplace:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Marketplace",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you are using fullPage.js.
The library overwrites the tab feature in order to keep the correct layout in certain occasions.

In order to test if that's your issue, you can try calling on the console:

```
$.fn.fullpage.destroy();
```

That will destroy all JS handlers used by fullPage.js but will keep the fullpage structure.

What really makes no sense there is that you have the issue only in production and not in dev.

I would in any case suggest you to update your fullpage.js version to the latest one. Fullpage.js 3.X. Which gets rid of jQuery and solve certain issues with the tab feature as you can see in its [changelog](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/releases).

Also, notice you only have to include fullPage.js once and you are doing it twice, which might lead to issues:

```
          "node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.min.js",
          "node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js"
```

Use only the extensions one.

Comment: Thank you!! Yeah, this production thing was really odd, but upgrading to the new version fixed everything! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. We have apps built in modern angular but we have never had this issue come up in any accessibility audit. Have you taken a look at the tab indexing? If you are using custom components, you may need to assign tabindex="0" to those elements that should have keyboard focus.